# Time short on thesis defense preperation

Tags: defense

I was supposed to defend my thesis in another week. But, due to the time schedule of one of the committee members I have to give the defense it tomorrow.

My status:

- Developed a rough defense presentation (probably need revision)
- Have less than a day to prepare

Can anyone advise me a plan as to defend this successfully?

EDIT :

**RESULT : FOLLOWED ALL ADVISES POSTED HERE AND DEFENDED SUCCESSFULLY ! THANK YOU ALL !**

[image: Final Stage]

Comment: See it like this. Prepare as best as you can which I am sure you will succeed at. But then if things don't go as planned, you could say you didn't have enough time to prepare without sounding like blaming that other professor... good plan ? :)

Comment: So how did it go ?

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Woo-hoo! Congrats!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Call together your graduate school friends, and set aside a two hour block of time.
2. Give them the presentation in its current form.
3. Receive (possibly scathing) feedback and take good notes.
4. Go fix the presentation.
5. If your friends are up for it, repeat the process, but not more than once.
6. Practice at least two more times before tomorrow.
7. Give the defense tomorrow, and pass.

Good luck!

(8. Buy lots of beer for your buddies who gave you help to pull this thing together.)

Comment: 9. Buy pizza also for friends who helped

Comment: 10. Remember to send thank you notes/emails to the friends. Those who show up are probably those who care about you.